# Semi-slick 29x2.4 (or larger) tires

Tags: tire, 29er

I have a set of Velocity Dually 29” wheels. The interior rim width is 39mm. I currently have Surly Knard tires but get a lot of buzz when riding on pavement. Ideally, I'd like a set of tires that run smoother on pavement but still good for mild-offroad/gravel.

What properties should I look for in a tire for my needs?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I use slicks on offroad gravel ( forest tracks in the nordmarka, Oslo ) quite 
happily, if you drop the pressure so there's more traction

Comment: Look for tyres that have a tread pattern with a solid and unbroken "rim" of rubber on the middle.  Most of your road riding is straight and forward, so this keeps a "slick" surface in contact with the road.  When off-road you're leaning more, and the surface tends to be less flat and also softer so you sink in a bit more.  This allows the shoulder knobblies to get some bite.

Comment: The biggest slick 29er tire that I know of is the Schwalbe Big Apple which comes in a 2.35.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but have you tried increasing the tire pressure for pavement use? Lower psi -> larger contact patch -> more noise, generally speaking...